# How to deal with equal & similar arguments for a function?

Tags: plugin-development, pagination, customization, wp-link-pages

I'm currently extending my pagination plugin, after a hint by @toscho. So the plugin will now use the same filters, hooks and arguments as the native wordpress pagination functions.

My problem is that the different wp functions name their arguments ... different.

#### Example:

*This is how you change the text for the "Next" link.*

- `wp_link_page()` = `'nextpagelink'`
- `paginate_links()` = `'next_text'`

After retrieving the input in the class, I `wp_parse_args( $args, $this->defaults );` my arguments and then `extract` them.

#### Problem:

When I now allow both `'nextpagelink'` & `'next_text'` as valid arguments, how would i deal with them? Which would I check first? Do I need to set some priority, so one overrules (if both are set) the other?

#### Example:

This example shows my dilemmas:

- Which one has the higher priority? How can I avoid deciding?
- It's really long code just for deciding what to do with 2 vars.

Code:

```
if ( $nextpagelink && $next_text ) 
{
    // CASE 1: both are set
    // which one should I take now?
}
elseif ( $nextpagelink )
{
    // CASE 2: only one is set - should this one override the next one?
    // set something
}
elseif ( $next_text )
{
    // CASE 3: only one is set - should this be overridden by the previous one?
    // set
}
else
{
    // CASE 4: none is set - apply default
    // set default
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_link_pages()` and `paginate_links()` work in different contexts: The first on a single paginated page, the latter on an archive. So `is_archive()` should be your criterion to decide which text you use, or better: which filter you use in `apply_filters()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since both of them need to exist to get in to the first if statement, couldn't you do something like this?

```
if ( $nextpagelink && $next_text ) {
   // set both variables
}else {
   // set default
}
```

or if you wanted to only work with one, regardless as to whether the other exists you could do this:

```
if ( $nextpagelink || $next_text ) {
   if ( $nextpagelink ) {
       // set something
   }

   if ( $next_text ) {
       // set
   }
}else {
   // set default
}
```